# python function not returning correct value

Tags: python, function, return

```
def myLog(x,b):
    def logCall(x,b,cnt):
        if (int(x) < b):
            return cnt
        else:
            cnt+= 1
            logCall(int((int(x)/b)),b,cnt)

    return logCall(x,b,0)

res=myLog(16,2)
print res
```

This function should return a a value of 4. But it returns None. When I print the value of cnt, I see the correct value. But when I return it, I get a value of None

Comment: this sort of tail-recursive function is just _begging_ to be converted to an iterative solution!

Answer (score 6):

You are not returning the recursive call:

```
else:
    cnt += 1
    logCall(int((int(x)/b)),b,cnt)
```

You function instead just ends there and you return `None` instead, the default for functions ending without an explicit `return`.

Return the recursive result:

```
else:
    cnt += 1
    return logCall(int((int(x)/b)),b,cnt)
```

Recursive calls don't magically make the calling frame return too; the call to `logCall()` is *just like any other function call*, you still need to handle the returned value.

With that change, your code returns the expected value:

```
>>> def myLog(x,b):
...     def logCall(x,b,cnt):
...         if (int(x) < b):
...             return cnt
...         else:
...             cnt+= 1
...             return logCall(int((int(x)/b)),b,cnt)
...     return logCall(x,b,0)
... 
>>> myLog(16,2)
4
```

There is no need to use `int()` all over the place; your inputs are already integers. And if you want to do integer division only, use the `//` floor division operator.

You probably want to add some whitespace for readability, and the `else` is optional, since you are already exiting the function if the `if` test is true. L

Last but not least, you can give `cnt` a default value, no need to nest your functions:

```
def myLog(x, b, cnt=0):
    if x < b:
        return cnt
    return myLog(x // b, b, cnt + 1)
```

Comment: why there is a need for type conversion here `if (int(x) < b):` since we are passing only the integer values?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I didn't look at the actual code itself. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

A variant, Python 3 closure;

```
def myLog(x,b):
    def logCall(cnt=0):
    nonlocal x
    if x < b:
        return cnt
    x /= b
    return logCall(cnt+1)
return logCall

res=myLog(16,2)
res()
```

for Python 2 closure, pass list;

```
def myLog(l):
    def logCall(cnt=0):
    if l[0] < l[1]:
        return cnt
    l[0] /= l[1]
    return logCall(cnt+1)
return logCall

res=myLog(16,2)
res()
```